# How to use expression inside another expression in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working ot `ASP.NET Web Forms` application. I needed to implement some conditional logic inside my repeater so I end up with this inside the Repater's `ItemTemplate` :

```
<%# Eval("Id").ToString() == "0" ? 
"<button onclick=\"__doPostBack('addRow', '')\">+</button>" :
"<button onclick=\"removeRow()\">-</button>" %>
```

This is working fine for adding a row since it's always appended to the end. However when I remove row with the `removeRow` function I need to specify which row the user want to remove and the easies way would be to just pass the `Id` to the `removeRow()` function. I tried to to it with something like this:

```
 "<button onclick=\"removeRow(" + '<%#Eval("Id")%>' + ")\">-</button>" %>
```

But it's not working. Often this is matter of findinf the correct syntax, but I tried a lot of variations.

Comment: will you please show removeRow()

Comment: @Amol I haven't wrote it yet since I'm not able to use it. I used a similar approach here - `<button onclick="delete('<%# Eval("Id") %>'); return false;">Delete</button>` and it's working fine, but this is written directly into the HTML of the page and not inside expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
OnClientClick="return Call(this)"
```

Then In function

```
function Call(ctrl)
{
  var row=ctrl.parentNode.parentNode;//to get GridviewRow
  var rowIndex=row.rowIndex;//row index of that row.
  //Put your code here to delete
 }
```

You can use this logic to delete record.

Comment: it's jsut an `HTML` button. Not server control. And it's not very clear how to pass `this`. Using server control is also not very clear because then I get some sort of validation error.

Comment: Will please give me more detail so that i can figure out.

Comment: Well, I find a workaround. You can use `Eval` as many timea as you want, but at least for now I don't know how to call it inside an expression because you get the error that it's allowed to use `Eval` only in databinding. However ternary operator work, so if I want to show/hide something conditionally I render two buttons and - `<%# Eval("Id") == "0" ? "style=display:none" : "" %> and in the second just `!="0"`.

Comment: The problems with server buttons - I don't remember exactly but when you render dynamically `<asp:button` at least in my case when I click it I get `pageVerification` or something like that is enabled and.. I really don't remember, some issue, and the suggestion was to disable this option which I didn't want to do and if I render just a plain `HTML` button then I couldn't find how to pass the reference `this` because it's either `window` or is recognized as `HTML` markup if I try something like "myFunction("+ this + ")". So those are the two problems. I'll be glad if you know solutions.